# QObject::connect: No such signal runtime warning - cannot find the reasion for

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am working on **async multithreaded server**, based on [this example](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Asynchronous_QTcpServer_QThreadPool.php). Now, I the following method:

```
void UeClient::ueSlotReadyRead()
{
    QList<QVariant> incomingData=QList<QVariant>();
    QByteArray incomingMessage=this->ueSocket()->readAll();

    UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand incomingCommand=UePOSCommProtocol::ueDecodeCommand(incomingMessage,
                                                                                        incomingData);

    UeTask* ueTask=new UeTask("testDb",
                              "testUsername",
                              "testPassword",
                              "localhost",
                              "3306",
                              incomingCommand);

    connect(ueTask,
            SIGNAL(ueSignalTaskFinished(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand,
                                        QByteArray)),
            this,
            SLOT(ueSlotFetchData(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand,
                                 QByteArray)),
            Qt::QueuedConnection);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(ueTask);
}   // ueSlotReadyRead
```

I get following runtime warning/error in `QtCreator`:

> QObject::connect: No such signal UeTask::ueSignalTaskFinished(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand, QByteArray) in ../../../net/ueclient.cpp:55

Here is **UeTask** class header file, from which we can see `ueSignalTaskFinished(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& executedCommand, QByteArray& fetchedData);` **IS declared**:

```
#ifndef UETASK_H
#define UETASK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QUuid>
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QByteArray>

#include "../../uePOSCommProtocol/uecommands.h"
#include "database/models/uefieldindexes.h"
#include "database/models/uequeries.h"

/*!
 * \brief The UeTask class
 */
class UeTask : public QObject,
               public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /*!
     * \brief m_ueDatabaseName
     */
    QString m_ueDatabaseName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueUserName
     */
    QString m_ueUserName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_uePassword
     */
    QString m_uePassword;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueHostName
     */
    QString m_ueHostName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_uePort
     */
    QString m_uePort;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueCommand
     */
    UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand m_ueCommand;

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabaseName
     * @return database name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseName() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabaseName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabaseUserName
     * @return database user name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseUserName() const
        { return this->m_ueUserName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabasePassword
     * @return database password
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabasePassword() const
        { return this->m_uePassword; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabasHost
     * @return database host name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabasHost() const
        { return this->m_ueHostName; }

    /*!
     * @brief uePort
     * @return database host port
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseHostPort() const
        { return this->m_uePort; }

    /*!
     * \brief ueCommand
     * \return task command
     */
    inline UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& ueCommand()
        { return this->m_ueCommand; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatbaseName
     * @param name
     */
    inline void ueSetDatbaseName(const QString& name)
        { this->m_ueDatabaseName=name; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseUserName
     * @param userName
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseUserName(const QString& userName)
        { this->m_ueUserName=userName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabasePassword
     * @param password
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabasePassword(const QString& password)
        { this->m_uePassword=password; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseHostName
     * @param hostName
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseHostName(const QString& hostName)
        { this->m_ueHostName=hostName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseHostPort
     * @param port
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseHostPort(const QString& port)
        { this->m_uePort=port; }

    /*!
     * \brief ueSetCommand
     * \param command
     */
    inline void ueSetCommand(const UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& command)
        { this->m_ueCommand=command; }

public:
    /*!
     * @brief UeTask
     */
    explicit UeTask(const QString& databaseName,
                    const QString& userName,
                    const QString& password,
                    const QString& hostName,
                    const QString& port,
                    const UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& command);

protected:
    /*!
     * @brief run
     */
    void run();

signals:
    /*!
     * \brief ueSignalTaskFinished
     * \param executedCommand
     * \param fetchedData
     */
    void ueSignalTaskFinished(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& executedCommand,
                              QByteArray& fetchedData);

    /*!
     * @brief ueSignalDatabaseConnectionOk
     */
    void ueSignalDatabaseConnectionOk();

    /*!
     * @brief ueSignalDatabaseConnectionError
     * @param error
     */
    void ueSignalDatabaseConnectionError(const QSqlError& error);
};

#endif // UETASK_H
```

Why the hell am I a getting this runtime warning/error and `signal` is **NOT** connected to `slot`? This might be some dumb mistake made, but I have been struggling with this bug for several hours ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem via @peppe's answer and I've added `const` to `SIGNAL`'s declaration:

```
#ifndef UETASK_H
#define UETASK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QUuid>
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QByteArray>

#include "../../uePOSCommProtocol/uecommands.h"
#include "database/models/uefieldindexes.h"
#include "database/models/uequeries.h"

/*!
 * \brief The UeTask class
 */
class UeTask : public QObject,
               public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /*!
     * \brief m_ueDatabaseName
     */
    QString m_ueDatabaseName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueUserName
     */
    QString m_ueUserName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_uePassword
     */
    QString m_uePassword;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueHostName
     */
    QString m_ueHostName;

    /*!
     * \brief m_uePort
     */
    QString m_uePort;

    /*!
     * \brief m_ueCommand
     */
    UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand m_ueCommand;

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabaseName
     * @return database name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseName() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabaseName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabaseUserName
     * @return database user name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseUserName() const
        { return this->m_ueUserName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabasePassword
     * @return database password
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabasePassword() const
        { return this->m_uePassword; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueDatabasHost
     * @return database host name
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabasHost() const
        { return this->m_ueHostName; }

    /*!
     * @brief uePort
     * @return database host port
     */
    inline const QString& ueDatabaseHostPort() const
        { return this->m_uePort; }

    /*!
     * \brief ueCommand
     * \return task command
     */
    inline UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& ueCommand()
        { return this->m_ueCommand; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatbaseName
     * @param name
     */
    inline void ueSetDatbaseName(const QString& name)
        { this->m_ueDatabaseName=name; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseUserName
     * @param userName
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseUserName(const QString& userName)
        { this->m_ueUserName=userName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabasePassword
     * @param password
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabasePassword(const QString& password)
        { this->m_uePassword=password; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseHostName
     * @param hostName
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseHostName(const QString& hostName)
        { this->m_ueHostName=hostName; }

    /*!
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseHostPort
     * @param port
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseHostPort(const QString& port)
        { this->m_uePort=port; }

    /*!
     * \brief ueSetCommand
     * \param command
     */
    inline void ueSetCommand(const UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& command)
        { this->m_ueCommand=command; }

public:
    /*!
     * @brief UeTask
     */
    explicit UeTask(const QString& databaseName,
                    const QString& userName,
                    const QString& password,
                    const QString& hostName,
                    const QString& port,
                    const UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& command);

protected:
    /*!
     * @brief run
     */
    void run();

signals:
    /*!
     * \brief ueSignalTaskFinished
     * \param executedCommand
     * \param fetchedData
     */
    void ueSignalTaskFinished(const UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand& executedCommand,
                              const QByteArray& fetchedData);

    /*!
     * @brief ueSignalDatabaseConnectionOk
     */
    void ueSignalDatabaseConnectionOk();

    /*!
     * @brief ueSignalDatabaseConnectionError
     * @param error
     */
    void ueSignalDatabaseConnectionError(const QSqlError& error);
};

#endif // UETASK_H
```

Then I had to [register meta type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) with:

```
qRegisterMetaType<UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand>("UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand");
```

in constructor of upper class:

```
UeClient::UeClient(QObject *parent,
                   UeSettings* const settings)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand>("UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand");

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(10);

    this->ueSetSettings(settings);
}   // constructor
```

and now it works!

Answer (score 5):

The signature of your signal does not match the signature of what you wrote in the `SIGNAL` macro -- those are non-const references:

```
SIGNAL(ueSignalTaskFinished(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand&, // reference
                            QByteArray&)), //ditto
```

Usage of non-const references as signal arguments is already suspicious enough, and using them with queued connections is definitely wrong. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: with these two parameters I want to transfer data from `ueSignalTaskFinished` to `slot` so I can process fetched data, is this wrong  way to do it?!

Comment: Why not passing by reference to const then?

Answer (score 2):

signals signatures are reference types (UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand&, QByteArray&). you're trying to connect signal to slot with another signature.

Comment: note that it would have matched if it were a const reference